# How to properly work with water-immersion microscope lenses

Tags: optics, visible-light, water, microscopy, experimental-technology

I've recently got Olympus water immersion lens (no cover glass), and I really like it, but it seems it requires completely different approach to work.

On conventional lenses - you put specimen on a slide, optionally cover with a cover glass, optionally put a droplet of immersion oil - and you are done.

But here layer of water is about ~6mm thick and It cannot stay this way without container (unlike 0.15mm thick immersion oil). Bottom of regular chemistry beakers is not flat. I must be missing some regular/standard way of working with such lenses, or don't know name of standard container for such operations to google for.

Can you suggest proper way of working with such lenses?

My specimens are microchips, so container flatness should not be worse than of regular slide glass (±1μm-2μm).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I don't know anything about this but) Have you tried Olympus support  http://www.olympus-lifescience.com/en/contact-us/ 
You may have to tel the computer you need a repair/service, but I'm sure the humans will understand.

Answer (score 0):

I second [JLMCarter's Answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/301376/26076) about getting in contact with the service department at Olympus.

I'm certainly not a real microscopist, but I design this kind of thing for a living and see many real microscopists at work and I'm almost certain I've seen this exact lens used without the problems you describe. I suspect there may be one of two things wrong:

1). There may be something contaminating the waterproof snout of the lens that's interfering with the water-objective contact angle and thus the capiliarity.

2). The optical module may not have been properly seated in the outer housing. If you look this lens's specifications up, its working distance is meant to be 3.5mm. 6mm is way out. This problem would explain why your lens is still working optically very well - the lens groups are mounted in a self-contained brass tube which maintains their alignment, and then this whole group is slidden into the outer housing which contains the RMS thread for attachment to the turret as well as all the manufacturer's bedazzling marketting livery. This lens is an infinity conjugate, so an unintended axial displacement of 2.5mm (which would explain the 6mm working distance) would make no difference whatsoever to the lens's optical alignment - it would still have perfect optical performance.

Clearly you'll need the service people for 2), and you'll need them for 1) too to ask what solvents can safely be used to clean your lens with.